# Ansible - Trigger Fail when string not in variable

Tags: ansible

I'm gathering facts via SNMP but I want trigger a failure if a string is not found within one of the OID responses.

Below is my Playbook. But I cannot get it to trigger.

Note: Im using Ansible 2.8.3

```
 tasks:
    - name: "TASK 1: GATHER FACTS VIA SNMP"
      snmp_facts:
        host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
        version: v3
        level: authPriv
        integrity: sha
        privacy: aes
        username: "{{ item.user }}"
        authkey: "{{ item.pwd }}"
        privkey: "{{ item.privacy }}"
      with_items: "{{ snmp_users }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      notify: snmp_facts_collected

    - debug:
        msg: "SNMP System Name: {{ ansible_sysname }} SNMP OID: {{ ansible_sysobjectid }} ansible_sysdescr {{ ansible_sysdescr }} "

  handlers:
    - name: "HANDLER 1: Check SNMP Response"
      listen: snmp_facts_collected
      fail:
        msg: parse err
      when: "{{ 'Xisco NX-OS' not in ansible_sysdescr }}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module `snmp_facts` does not report `changed: true`. Register and see the `result`.

```
tasks:
    - name: "TASK 1: GATHER FACTS VIA SNMP"
      snmp_facts:
        host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
        ...
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result
```

The debug gives

```
    "result": {
        "ansible_facts": {
         ...
        "changed": false, 
        "failed": false
    }
}
```

`"changed": false` is the reason the handler is not triggered. If you want to test `ansible_sysdescr` just put it as the next task in the play

```
  - fail:
      msg: parse err
    when: ansible_sysdescr is not search('Xisco NX-OS')
```

Answer (score 0):

From reading the Ansible [When](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement) documentation, I'd suggest removing `{{` & `}}` from your `when:` clause:

```
when: 'Xisco NX-OS' not in ansible_sysdescr
```

If it's not enough, try `debug:` module on `ansible_sysdescr` key to visually check if that exact phrase is present.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is down to the handler only being triggered when the changed state is changed. Due to snmp facts not making a changed it therefor does not trigger.